# Why wont the second timer start/label update once the button is pressed?

Tags: swift

I have this piece of code:

```
    @IBAction func startbtn(_ sender: Any) {

    display = Int(timeinput.text ?? "") ?? 0
    secondDisplay = Int(insertSecondTime.text ?? "") ?? 0
    mytimer.invalidate()
    mytimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: 
    #selector(Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
    if display == 0 {
        secondTimer.invalidate()
        secondTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: 
         #selector(Action2), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
}
```

When the button is pressed, it starts the first countdown fine, but it doesnt start the second when the first display = 0. Any tips?

Comment: This is not reproducible but since all variables in the code are defined outside the scope of the startbtn function we have no idea how they are initialised and where and when they might change

Comment: Please try to give full code which you try so one can help you with issue you face